# Install hyperv cmdlet on workstation

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a script that starts new HyperV VM's on a remote server using powershell

```
New-VM
Get-VM
```

I want to run this script on my desktop, however I get the following error.

```
 the term 'new-vm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

I can't figure out how to install the new-vm cmdlet on my workstation

```
Get-WindowsFeature
the target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a windows client-based operating system

Install-windowsFeature hyperv-
    the target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a windows client-based operating system
```

I am very new to powershell, and don't do much with windows.

How can I install the cmdlet `New-VM` on a Windows 8 machine?

**Update**

Also tried the following.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Hyper-V-Tools
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Hyper-V-PowerShell
```

I see hyperv tools in the following command

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | sort state
Microsoft-Hyper-V
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Tools-All
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Powershell
```

**Update 2**

I almost got it installed, but it gives this error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Powershell
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it installed. The powershell cmdlet has parents that can be installed by adding `-all`.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Powershell -all
```

You will need to reboot before the cmdlet is available.